# Evaluating the limit of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to evaluate the limit of the following series:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}$$

I have already decomposed the fraction into the following:
$$\frac{2}{k+2}-\frac{3}{2(k+3)}-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$$

I am stuck at this point. I don't see what positive terms cancel each other out with their negative counterparts between the three. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, partial fraction decomposition doesn't work perfectly all the time.

Comment: This is part of an assignment I have. Apparently the person who wrote it insists that this be solved through fraction decomposition.

Comment: Is that mandatory for the answers?  Because, for example, use of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) could do this.

Comment: I'm afraid it is mandatory, yes.

Comment: If that is so, then you should place that remark in the question.

Comment: You may have a sign error in the PFD

Comment: You do have a sign error. The second term has no -3. As a general tip, when something doesn't seem to be working, go on wolfram alpha and check. It will give you the correct PDF, correct value of the series, and correct partial sum formula.

Comment: The error has been corrected. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your partial fraction decomposition is incorrect, and has an extra minus sign in front of the $3$.  You just have to write out the terms, and you are left with $$\frac 12\left(-\frac 12+\frac 43-\frac 13\right)$$ with everything else cancelling, so the answer is $$\frac 14$$

Comment: Oh, that was a typo. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. If this is the answer you want you can accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)} = \frac{1}{2}[3\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}]$$
Split the individual summations again using partial fractions and use the method of difference.
$$\frac{1}{2}[3\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{k+2} - \frac{1}{k+3})-\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2})] = \frac{1}{2}[3\cdot\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2}] = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Isn't telescoping sums good enough?

Comment: Is something wrong? I don't actually know what telescoping sums is.

Comment: It's right, but you could've made the last statement much simpler.  I suggest you look up what a telescoping sum is, as it is a useful piece of knowledge.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) says "In mathematics, a telescoping series is a series whose partial sums eventually only have a fixed number of terms after cancellation. The cancellation technique, with part of each term cancelling with part of the next term, is known as the method of differences." So haven't I actually unknowingly used telescoping series? I don't see what simplification I am missing.

Comment: I just meant that it would be far easier to say "and this is a telescoping sum..." instead of actually doing more work.  Indeed, the first line would've sufficed.

Comment: Oh, I see now what you meant.

Comment: Lol, anyways, its still a good answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll multiply everything by two to deal with fractions and then divide my answer by two:
$$-\frac3{k+3}+\frac4{k+2}-\frac1{k+1}$$
Let us consider the $k$,$k+1$, and $k+2$ cases:
$$\left(-\color{blue}{\frac3{4}}+\frac4{3}-\frac1{2}\right)+\left(-\color{red}{\frac3{5}}+\color{blue}{\frac4{4}}-\frac1{3}\right)+\left(-\frac3{6}+\color{red}{\frac4{5}}-\color{blue}{\frac1{4}}\right)+\left(-\frac3{7}+\frac4{6}-\color{red}{\frac1{5}}\right)+...$$
As you can see, everything except the $\frac43$, the $\frac12$, the $\frac13$, and the last two fractions cancel out, leaving:
$$-\frac12+\frac43-\frac13-\frac3{n+3}+\frac1{n+2}$$
Letting $n\to\infty$
$$-\frac12+\frac43-\frac13-0+0=\frac12$$
Dividing the answer by two leaves the desired answer, $\frac14$.

For more information, look up [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).