# Prove that the following series converges to 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)} = 1$$
The hint my teacher game me was to use partial fractions and observe it is a telescoping sum, but I can´t see how the elements of the sum cancel out.

edit:
The partial fractions I got were:

$$\frac{-2}{n+1} + \frac{8}{n+2} + \frac{-6}{n+3}$$

Comment: What did partial fractions give ?

Comment: Decompose the term into two fractions of the form $\frac{A}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{B}{(n+2)(n+3)}$

Comment: I tried to decompose it into 3 terms and found A, B, and C. But the problem is I can´t seem to see how the elements of the sum would cancel.

Comment: Did you read the hint posted?

Comment: @ÁlvaroRomo You are almost there jus divide $\frac{8}{n+2}$ into two suitable parts.

Comment: Oh okay I see now. So now what I have to do is observe it is a telescoping sum right?

Comment: @ÁlvaroRomo Yes exacly only 2 terms survive!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating the limit of a series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042168/evaluating-the-limit-of-a-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{4n}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=-\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{2}{n+2}+\frac{6}{n+2}-\frac{6}{n+3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The telescoping works as follows:

$$\begin{align}
n\to&-\frac2{n+1}+\frac8{n+2}\color{green}{-\frac6{n+3}}\\
n+1\to&-\frac2{n+2}\color{green}{+\frac8{n+3}}-\frac6{n+4}\\
n+2\to&\color{green}{-\frac2{n+3}}+\frac8{n+4}-\frac6{n+5}\\
\end{align}$$

and the green terms cancel each other. This continues for the next $n$'s, three by three terms. But the initial terms remain

$$\begin{align}
1\to&\color{blue}{-\frac2{2}+\frac8{3}}-\frac6{4}\\
2\to&\color{blue}{-\frac2{3}}+\frac8{4}-\frac6{5}\\
3\to&-\frac2{5}+\frac8{6}-\frac6{7}
\end{align}$$

and they sum to $1$.